# Which and what type indexes should i create to optimize these mysql querys?

Tags: mysql, indexing, hash, b-tree

I'm thinking about creating an hashed index in (1) because it uses equalities and bit map on (2) because the state can only be 'accepted' or 'not accepted'. What else can i use? And also my problem is that i can only try b-tree indexes on mysql oracle..

```
(1)select​ R.user_id from​ rent as R
inner​ ​join​ supervise S on​
R.adress = S.adress 
and​ R.space_id = S.space_id
group​ ​by​ R.user_id
having​ ​count​(​distinct​ S.supervisor_id) = 1

(2) select​ ​distinct​ P.adress, P.code from​ space as P where​ (P.adress, P.code) ​not​ ​in ​(
select​ P.adress, P.code ​from​ space as P
natural​ ​join​ rent as R
natural​ ​join​ state as E ​where​ E.state = ‘accepted’)
```

Comment: Why are there ['ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) characters in your code? --- Why is your text literal using funky apostrophes (`‘` and `’`, not `'`)?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no directly limiting criterias in query #1, it will likely be done using a merge join, and no index will improve that.

For query #2, how selective is the criteria `E.state = 'accepted'`? If very selective (< 5-15% of query result), then index on `E.state`, indexes for the joins from E to R and from R to P, and index on `P.adress, P.code`.

Answer (score 0):

Composite index on each table:

```
INDEX(space_id, adress)
```

Don't use `WHERE(a,b) IN ...` -- it performs very poorly.

Don't use `IN ( SELECT ... )` -- it often performs poorly.

Instead, use a `JOIN`.

For `state`, have

```
INDEX(state)
```

(or is it already the `PRIMARY KEY`?)

If you need more help after all that, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.